# Hash symbol in intent-filter data path

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-manifest, intentfilter

this is a part of my `AndroidMaifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="myhost.com" />
</intent-filter>
```

And now I want to open following links with my app:
`myhost.com/my/path` and `myhost.com/my/#/path`. Both of them open in app, but for the first one `getIntent().getData().getPath()` returns `/my/path` (which is correct), but for second one it returns `/my` (where it should be `/my/#/path`). Am I thinking wrong or `#` is somehow bugged and it cuts path?

Comment: Please include the code where you try to open the links so we can look at it as well. My suspicion is that you may have to encode the URL.

Comment: I simply click the link in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer. Instead of

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData()
```

I use now

```
String uriString = Uri.encode(getIntent().getDataString(), "/:?&="); // I'm not sure if those are all characters that should be allowed
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
```

I hope it helps someone!